# PHP & jQuery .load() - If you visit the .load() URL, redirect back

Tags: php, jquery, redirect, load

I am using jQuery load, to load some data from an external file like this:

> $("#div1").load("test.php");

Now this works fine but I want users not to be able to visit test.php. In case they type in the URL test.php, get redirected to index.php

I tried this:

I inserted in my index: `<? $fromIndex = true; ?>` and this in my test.php file:

```
<? 
$fromIndex = true;
if(!isset($fromIndex) || !$fromIndex) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}
 ?>
```

The redirection works great if you visit test.php but the load doesn't work from index.php.

EDIT: **Note:**  I wouldn't mind changing the test.php to .xml ? Or anything else that would help. The content I'm loading is few `<option>`'s

Can someone help me please?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not really a way for you to prevent a user visiting a URL directly, and yet still allow AJAX access to that same URL. A simple way to dissuade them, though, would be to either A) send the response back as a JSON object (which makes it pretty useless when accessed directly), or B) append a GET parameter to the URL and perform your redirect when that parameter is absent.

```
$("#div1").load("test.php?ajax=1");
```

and

```
<? 
if( !isset( $_GET['ajax'] ) || $_GET['ajax']!=1 ) {
    header( "Location: index.php" );
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: @jQuerybeast: Thanks for the heads up - forgot the closing square bracket. Should be good now.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's AJAX functions all send a `X-Requested-With` header with the contents `XMLHttpRequest`. You can use this to do what you want, but don't use it as an anti-abuse feature - it's trivially defeated. It should only be used to be helpful to users who stumble across the URL, or to present them with a helpful error page instead of say, a JSON feed.